# Should I use TaskCompletionSource to make a method that holds the thread until a state is reached?

Tags: c#

I have a class that defines an internal state machine. The state of those objects may be changed by a parallel thread.

I would like to write a function that stops execution until the object has reached the state called Idle, so that the state can be used as a kind of mutex.

My solution has been to define the following method in the class:

```
    public Task WaitForIdle()
    {
        // TaskCompletionSource need a return type, so I define is as bool
        // even though that return is never used.
        wait_tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        return wait_tcs.Task;
    }
```

(wait_tcs is a global TaskCompletionSource variable).

Then on the method I use to change the state I've added this:

```
    private void ChangeState(State new_state)
    {
        state = new_state;

        // If we are waiting for Idle mark finish the task and delete it.
        if(wait_tcs != null)
        {
            wait_tcs.SetResult(false);
            wait_tcs = null;
        }
     ...
```

With this I can wait for an object to reach the Idle state like this:

```
InstancedObject.WaitForIdle().Wait()
```

I could probably put the Wait inside the method, but this way I could also save the waiting task in a variable and use it in a Task.AwaitAll, if I ever need to do that.

But is there a better way to do this? I'm not sure that I am using TaskCompletionSource as it is intended.

PD: Of course I could do a simple method with a do-while loop that runs until state==Idle, but I'd like to do something better than that.

Comment: can you elaborate what are you trying to do? plus how r you defining wait_tcs in one function then using it in another?

Comment: *write a function that stops execution until the object has reached the state*, this is exactly what [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=net-6.0) can be used for.